# PHP session variables getting lost after a header redirect

Tags: php

I cannot figure this out. Sometimes after the redirect (see code below), the session variables are lost. Any ideas?

Note the script is initially called with ?p=1&u=2&k=3.
As you can see, the script redirects to itself. The session variables something are lost after the redirect.

```
<?php

session_start();

if ((isset($_SESSION['p'])) and ($_SESSION['p'] != "")) {
    // do something
} else {
    $_SESSION['p'] = $_GET['p'];
    $_SESSION['w'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    $_SESSION['u'] = $_GET['u'];
    $_SESSION['k'] = $_GET['k'];

    header("Location: http://".$_SESSION['w'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."");
    exit();
}

?>
```

Cheers

Comment: Are you trying to access a $_SESSION variable in another script ? Well if that the case make sure to call session_start();

Comment: And why are you assigning a HTTP_HOST to a session variable?

Comment: Are you sure you call session_start() on all scripts?

Comment: thought the same but as he - according to him - redirects to the same script again this should not be a/the problem.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I redirect to the same script. This is the only script.

Answer (score 0):

Copied and pasted your code and it works just fine for me.
Do you maybe have some spaces or whatever before your `<?php`-tag?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No spaces. The problem is this is happening only sometimes. Very frustrating!

Comment: During your testing / development: Do you call any other PHP scripts which are on the same server? This also includes scripts that are not related in any kind to the one you posted here.

Comment: sure there are many scripts running on my server. some of them use sessions. do you think this could cause a problem?

Comment: it should not be but maybe some scripts e.g. interfer with your session cookie. by the way: you might check if a session cookie is set. If not you should enable it in the php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it happens.

Probably you have some misconfiguration on your `php.ini` file.

Or you don't have the right `session.save_path` or permissions to write there.

But if the problem persists, try this way:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['p']) {
    $_SESSION['p'] = $_GET['p'];
    $_SESSION['w'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    $_SESSION['u'] = $_GET['u'];
    $_SESSION['k'] = $_GET['k'];
}

//code comes here

?>
```

In my opinion, this is the way things should be done.